# Dividing Geographical region into equal sized grid and returning upper-left and lower-right of each cell

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create function to geographically divide a region into a equal sized grid of 50x50 (meters). The function needs to return the upper-left and lower-right geographical coordinates of each cell. I'm using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

upper_right = (33.775353, -111.566165)
lower_right = (33.273915, -111.566165)

upper_left = (33.775353, -112.439578)
lower_left = (33.273915, -112.439578)

cols = np.linspace(lower_left[1], lower_right[1], num=50)
rows = np.linspace(lower_left[0], upper_left[0], num=50)
```

I don't have any experience with numpy, and in fact that's my first time using it. So I'm not sure if the `linspace` is the better method for what I'm trying to do. Some guidance would be very helpful.

---

Update: I've managed to remove the redundancy by calculating the `upper_right` and `lower_right` in runtime. Also, I've moved everything to a function that accepts the `cell_size` (default `50`):

```py
import numpy as np


def calculate_grid(upper_left, lower_right, cell_size=50):
    upper_right = {'lat': upper_left['lat'], 'lon': lower_right['lon']}
    lower_left = {'lat': lower_right['lat'], 'lon': upper_left['lon']}
    # cols = np.linspace(lower_left['lon'], lower_right['lon'], num=cell_size)
    # rows = np.linspace(lower_left['lat'], upper_left['lat'], num=cell_size)
    pass


upper_left = {'lat': 33.775353, 'lon': -112.439578}
lower_right = {'lat': 33.273915, 'lon': -111.566165}

grid = calculate_grid(upper_left, lower_right)
print(grid)
```

Comment: Are you aware that latitude and longitude are angles and squares are not very common to divide a region and harder to calculate in spherical coordinates?

Comment: Do you want the cells to be 50 m x 50 m or do you want to separate the region into 50 columns and 50 rows?

Comment: I'm not, this is my first time doing something like this.

Comment: I would like the cells to be 50m by 50m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the approach of projecting the region to a local transverse mercator coordinate system using [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/).  Then I laid out the 50m grid, and finally convert from transverse mercator back to lat/lon.

```py
import math
import pyproj
import csv


def ll_to_xy(t, lon, lat):
    return t.transform(
        lon,
        lat,
        radians=False,
        direction=pyproj.enums.TransformDirection.FORWARD)

def xy_to_ll(t, x, y):
    lond, latd = t.transform(
        x,
        y,
        radians=False,
        direction=pyproj.enums.TransformDirection.INVERSE)
    return lond, latd


def generate_cells(xstep, ystep, upper_left, lower_right):
    # Transverse mercator coordinate reference system,
    # whose origin is in the middle of the region.
    lon_0 = upper_left['longitude'] + (lower_right['longitude'] - upper_left['longitude'])/2
    lat_0 = lower_right['latitude'] + (upper_left['latitude']   - lower_right['latitude'])/2
    geo_crs = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:4326") 
    tmerc_crs = pyproj.CRS.from_proj4(f'+proj=tmerc +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0={lon_0} +lat_0={lat_0} +units=m +no_defs')

    # Lon/lat to tmerc.
    ll_to_tmerc = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(geo_crs, tmerc_crs, always_xy=True)

    ul = ll_to_xy(ll_to_tmerc, upper_left['longitude'],  upper_left['latitude'])
    ur = ll_to_xy(ll_to_tmerc, lower_right['longitude'], upper_left['latitude'])
    lr = ll_to_xy(ll_to_tmerc, lower_right['longitude'], lower_right['latitude'])
    ll = ll_to_xy(ll_to_tmerc, upper_left['longitude'],  lower_right['latitude'])

    # Generate a grid, beginning with the upper left point.
    grid = []
    gx = ul[0]
    gy = ul[1]
    row = 0
    lon, lat = xy_to_ll(ll_to_tmerc, gx, gy)
    with open('grid_points.csv', 'w') as gpf:
        gpw = csv.writer(gpf)
        gpw.writerow(['longitude', 'latitude'])
        while lat > lower_right['latitude']:
            grid.append([])
            while lon <= lower_right['longitude']:
                lon, lat = xy_to_ll(ll_to_tmerc, gx, gy)
                grid[row].append((lon, lat))
                gpw.writerow([lon, lat])
                gx += xstep

            # Start the next row.
            gx = ul[0]
            row += 1
            gy -= ystep
            lon, lat = xy_to_ll(ll_to_tmerc, gx, gy)

    # Make cells from the grid points.
    cells = []
    for i in range(len(grid) - 1):
        cells.append([])
        for j in range(len(grid[0]) - 1):
            cells[i].append({ 'ul' : grid[i][j], 'lr' : grid[i+1][j+1]})
    return cells
            
region = {
    'upper_left': {
        'latitude': -23.6060507,
        'longitude': -46.627016 },
    'lower_right': {
        'latitude': -23.659132,
        'longitude': -46.565758 } }

print('UL', region['upper_left']['longitude'], region['upper_left']['latitude'])
print('LR', region['lower_right']['longitude'], region['lower_right']['latitude'])

cells = generate_cells(50.0, 50.0, region['upper_left'], region['lower_right'])


# Test the cell dimensions with a geodesic to verify
# they are really 50m x 50m.
g = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')

for (i, row) in enumerate(cells):
    for (j, col) in enumerate(row):
        # Measure top edge of cell[i][j].
        a12, a21, dx = g.inv(
            # From upper left corner.
            cells[i][j]['ul'][0],
            cells[i][j]['ul'][1],
            # To upper right corner.
            cells[i][j]['lr'][0],
            cells[i][j]['ul'][1],
            radians=False)
        # Measure left edge of cell[i][j].
        a12, a21, dy = g.inv(
            # From upper left corner.
            cells[i][j]['ul'][0],
            cells[i][j]['ul'][1],
            # to lower left corner.
            cells[i][j]['ul'][0],
            cells[i][j]['lr'][1],
            radians=False)

        # Measure diagonal.
        a12, a21, dd = g.inv(
            # From upper left corner.
            cells[i][j]['ul'][0],
            cells[i][j]['ul'][1],
            # to lower right corner.
            cells[i][j]['lr'][0],
            cells[i][j]['lr'][1],
            radians=False)

        h = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
        print('cells[{0}][{1}] '.format(i, j))
        print('  ul = {0} '.format(cells[i][j]['ul']))
        print('  lr = {0} '.format(cells[i][j]['lr']))
        print('  dx = {0} dy = {1} dd = {2} h = {3}'.format(dx, dy, dd, h))

        if j == 4: break
    if i == 4: break
```

Comment: Thank you @RustyWidebottom, this is almost right! What I need the function to return is the `upper-left` and `bottom-right` of each one of the cells. I'm working on your code to see if I can get there.

Comment: Updated my answer to return upper-left/lower-right coordinates of each cell.  Also added testing of each cell.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is kind of impossible at least while having the grind lines always oriented north-south and west-east. That is why the grid of the geographical coordinate system does not consist out of squares.

I wrote you code that creates a grid with a col length of approximately 50 m. It will not work near the poles and will have problems with distances crossing -180 and + 180 lon.

```
import math

meanRadius = 6371.0087714150598 # mean radius of the earth in km
colDistance = 0.05 # 50m circle distance between the points of the grid

northWest = (33.775353, -112.439578)

# The lat angle diffrence between two points 50 m circle distanc away
angleLat = (colDistance * 360) / (2 * math.pi * meanRadius)

latRadius = math.cos(math.radians(northWest[0])) * meanRadius
angleLon = (colDistance * 360) / (2 * math.pi * latRadius)

print("angleLat: {}".format(angleLat))
print("angleLon: {}".format(angleLon))
print("latRadius: {}".format(latRadius))

grid = []

for x in range(5):
    grid += [[]]
    for y in range(5):
        grid[x] += [(northWest[0] - x * angleLat, northWest[1] + y * angleLon)]

print(grid)
```

Output

```
angleLat: 0.00044966018387976883
angleLon: 0.0005409617010418813
latRadius: 5295.733450513392
[[(33.775353, -112.439578), (33.775353, -112.43903703829895), (33.775353, -112.43849607659791), (33.775353, -112.43795511489687), (33.775353, -112.43741415319583)], [(33.77490333981612, -112.439578), (33.77490333981612, -112.43903703829895), (33.77490333981612, -112.43849607659791), (33.77490333981612, -112.43795511489687), (33.77490333981612, -112.43741415319583)], [(33.774453679632245, -112.439578), (33.774453679632245, -112.43903703829895), (33.774453679632245, -112.43849607659791), (33.774453679632245, -112.43795511489687), (33.774453679632245, -112.43741415319583)], [(33.77400401944836, -112.439578), (33.77400401944836, -112.43903703829895), (33.77400401944836, -112.43849607659791), (33.77400401944836, -112.43795511489687), (33.77400401944836, -112.43741415319583)], [(33.77355435926448, -112.439578), (33.77355435926448, -112.43903703829895), (33.77355435926448, -112.43849607659791), (33.77355435926448, -112.43795511489687), (33.77355435926448, -112.43741415319583)]]
```

Full disclaimer I have not checked if the results are plausible there still might be some errors in the math.

For the math behind it and how the coordinate system works consult
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance